# custom ubuntu iso image with java

Tags: boot, java, iso, jre

I want to build custom Ubuntu image(.iso) file with JRE and my application. I've already built my application on ubuntu. This ubuntu image i'm going to build should only run my application.I want a system, that is only capable to run my application. The application should start while the system is starting. Where should i look for resources to implement this?? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No dash? No items on the launcher? No browser? .... That is going to be hard...

I would suggest to try and find a KIOSK version of Ubuntu and alter that (the answers in [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd/49679#49679) will help). Kiosk means it is suited for 1 task and 1 task only but this most times is a browser, music or video oriented system. Or  an information booth. Plus point here is that it is already restricted and stripped down.

- [Customize Ubuntu for a library Internet kiosk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk)
- http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/?ALLSTEPS

Here is an ISO for 12.04:

- http://jacob.steelsmith.org/category/section/ubuntu-kiosk-edition