# how to automatically reset ubuntu after rebooting computer

Tags: 12.04, reboot, reset

I am working in a university and we are using ubuntu for all the computers.  We are "updating" our students computers.

What we would like to do is to reset our computers everytime after we reboot the computers.  Basically delteling all the files as the computers are only there for printing and research.
I am sure that its possible but I am not exactly sure how to do it!

Any help will be wonderful!  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You can do this with hardware. It is called a "reborn" card: http://www.lenten.com/Products.asp Also have a look at "kiosk mode": http://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk

Comment: I'd suggest looking at LVM snapshots, as [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm#Snapshots) (there's more detail at the bottom of the page). NOTE: I don't actually do this myself, just a suggestion. I wont be able to help much more.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Lethe, a deep freeze like software for Ubuntu.

You can download Leethe from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lethe/).

Then follow the steps [from here](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/07/deep-freeze-like-software-for-ubuntu.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer!  it is very helpful but not exactly what I need (i wasn't 100% clear in my original question), I just want my home directory to be restored everytime to a default home directory, the rest of the OS can stay the same!  thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Lethe can do that. You can selectively freeze the mount points you want to be frozen (e.g. /home) Check [this link](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Flihuen.linti.unlp.edu.ar%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DGu%25C3%25ADa_de_instalaci%25C3%25B3n_de_Lethe)