# Ubuntu desktop with citrix receiver

Tags: boot, live-cd, iso, citrix

Is it possible to built an Ubuntu desktop which would autostart the Citrix Receiver after boot? The plan is for the user to see nothing other than the virtual desktop with the login screen.

Comment: yes. citrix receiver can be installed on Ubuntu. The rest is just  removing priviliges; kiosk mode with browser+citrix might be the easiest method. (and no it will not be easy and it will be a lengthy task).

Comment: Wasn't expecting it to be easy. So, any advice on how I can get started?

Comment: @Rinzwind Can I use the method you've suggested in the following post (http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) with Ubuntu-14.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize Ubuntu for a library Internet kiosk](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk)