# How to force user to run quiz after login and before displaying desktop

Tags: login, pam

I have a kid and I want to allow him to use the computer only after he solves a certain quiz at logon.

I can write a quiz application itself. What I don't know is how to set it up in the way, that computer doesn't show normal desktop until the quiz program decides so.

How can I do it? Should I use pam? But how can I make pam application interact with user graphically?

I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize Ubuntu for a library Internet kiosk](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk)

Comment: The difference being that instead of a browser, you run the app, and then start the Unity session if the question was answered correctly.

Comment: @muru Do you know how to start Unity session after the kiosk application finishes?

Comment: `gnome-session --session=ubuntu`, IIRC. You can check in `/usr/share/xsessions`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a super simple way. Have your quiz program run during the Xsession, right before the desktop gets launched.

For example, try creating a file (as root) called `/etc/X11/Xsession/95quiz` with the following contents:

```
xmessage "What is my favorite color?" -buttons "African Swallow,European Swallow,42" -print -center
```

Upon logging on, you will not be able to use the computer until the quiz program exits.

*Of course, the way I have it setup, all users of the computer will be quizzed, which seems fair to me. Running it from only your kid's .xsession is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)*