# User profile with only browser access

Tags: permissions, user-profile

I am setting up Ubuntu Mate in a standalone machine where I need to create a user with access only to a browser(firefox). Other applications should not be present or should not have permissions to execute. Tried few options like updating the PATH variable by removing access to other executable, but it is not replecting. How can this made possible?

Comment: Looks like you really want kiosk mode: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk, https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be very difficult to arrange via permissions, because there are many dependencies, some of which may even change under updates. This is not something I would advice.

Much simpler might be just to opt for a very straightforward window manager (tvfm for example), and start firefox from its login for that user. You than can close the user's capabilities further by blocking applicable config files from writing for that user.

This is not watertight, but would be enough for normal desktop users. If you need more help with aspects, just comment on it and I will extend this answer.