# Internet / cyber cafe software for 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, cybercafe

Is there any internet cafe software that can help manage an internet cafe automation. It will be great to have features like

1. Auto close session on time out ( set by mother PC )
2. Reminder for time out
3. Remote check on client PCs
4. Possible support for coupons / discount code
5. Bandwidth / Data counting and control
6. Billing
7. Control from mother PC

etc

Currently using stock Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity

Comment: Try this: http://mkahawa.sourceforge.net/index.php

Comment: I did see that from a 2011 post. UI is horrible, by the looks of it. Any other suggestion available ? Thanks.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [Customize Ubuntu for a library Internet kiosk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing mkahawa on ubuntu 14.04. It works flawlessly. You will need many dependencies to get that done.