# Create a live usb Ubuntu to run an application without desktop environment

Tags: 16.04, gtk, display-manager

I need to create a USB live ubuntu to run an application. I want to open my application after the boot as fullscreen without any other option to the end user.

I read that I should use Gtk+ or Qt5 if I want to run an app without a desktop environment or display manager so I created my app using Gtk+.

To be able to open the app without a desktop environment I added to .bashrc the following:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
while true; do ./myapp; done
```

I put it inside a while because sometimes I got the following error:

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(myapp:4918): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I suppose I was trying to run the application before the display manager is running.

Enable auto-login for the default user makes .bashrc on tty1 to be executed and my application is launched.

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
    [Service]
    ExecStart=
    ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noissue --autologin ubuntu %I $TERM
    Type=idle
```

To make it work I also needed to edit `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` so it doesn't launch the desktop environment.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

It is working however there are some points that I don't understand.

1 - Most of the answers to this problem say to edit ubuntu.desktop and change exec to my application however I wasn't able to make it work. It doesn't run Ubuntu desktop indeed but I wasn't able to make it run my app. I didn't find how I could debug why it was failing.

2 - I read that Gtk+ and Qt5 can use Wayland so I didn't a desktop environment neither a display manager, how could I do that?

3 - Which alternatives do you recommend to obtain the same result? The way I did it in .bashrc sounds a little bit hackish.

Thank you

Comment: I had originally marked this for close as duplicate, but I don't think it's a super good match.  You might look at the method used, to see if it helps you.  [https://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk)

Comment: @CharlesGreen I tried but it didin't work https://pastebin.com/z1fQQFbp